# Display object in template just like in devtools console

Tags: javascript, html, treeview, console.log

When we `console.log` any object we can inspect it in devTools very conveniently (expanding, collapsing etc.). I am creating my own devTools panel (chrome extension) and I need to emulate this behaviour in html template. Is there any easy way for doing it or maybe library made for it?